# How to determine the visible buffer width in characters

Tags: emacs, width, character

I'm using a custom modeline and I'm starting to get how to configure it but here I'm stuck as to how to get the info I want: I'd like to show, in each buffer's modeline, the width in characters of the buffer.

I'm also using linum-mode (with always at least two columns used) and ideally I'd like to deduce the number of characters used by linum from the width.

Comment: I think cobbal answer makes sense and is probably what you're looking for, but note that you asked for the width of a buffer and he gives you the width of a window.

Comment: @Stefan To my knowledge buffers don't have widths, just text and stuff. Consider a buffer displayed in more than one window at once, it has no intrinsic width. Perhaps you're thinking of frames instead of windows?

Comment: @cobbal: Yes, that's what I was getting at: buffers could have a width, i.e. the length longest line in the buffer, but it's basically never done and is probably not what he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `(window-width)` is what you're looking for, this doesn't include the characters used by `linum-mode` however you can get their width from `(window-margins)`

Comment: How do you run that?

Comment: @Geremia I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but it's just a (non-interactive) function. You can run arbitrary lisp code with `eval-expression` bound to `M-:` by default.

Comment: Thanks. How to do that is what I was asking about.